# Dynamic memory allocation + truncating a string issue

Tags: c, string, malloc, truncation

I've been fooling around with malloc, realloc and free in order to write some basic functions to operate on C strings (char*). I've encountered this weird issue when erasing the last character from a string. I wrote a function with such a prototype:

```
int string_erase_end (char ** dst, size_t size);
```

It's supposed to shorten the "dst" string by one character. So far I have come up with this code:

```
int string_erase_end (char ** dst, size_t size)
{
    size_t s = strlen(*dst) - size;
    char * tmp = NULL;
    if (s < 0) return (-1);
    if (size == 0) return 0;
    tmp = (char*)malloc(s);
    if (tmp == NULL) return (-1);
    strncpy(tmp,*dst,s);
    free(*dst);
    *dst = (char*)malloc(s+1);
    if (*dst == NULL) return (-1);
    strncpy(*dst,tmp,s);
    *dst[s] = '\0';
    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

In main(), when I truncate strings (yes, I called malloc on them previously), I get strange results. Depending on the number of characters I want to truncate, it either works OK, truncates a wrong number of characters or throws a segmentation fault.

I have no experience with dynamic memory allocation and have always used C++ and its std::string to do all such dirty work, but this time I need to make this work in C. I'd appreciate if someone helped me locate and correct my mistake(s) here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first strncpy() doesn't put a '\0' at the end of tmp.

Also, you could avoid a double copy: *dst = tmp;

Comment: By the way, if (s < 0) ... is never true.

Comment: Thank you, it works flawlessly now. I'll remember to take the '\0' character into consideration next time.

Comment: The problem is the odd semantics of strncpy. I think it is a throw back to the time when Unix directory entries had up to 14 characters, non nul terminated if there were exactly 14.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed in strncpy's description that it didn't copy the final nul character if the number of characters copied was lower than the source string's length...

Answer (score 2):

According to your description your function is supposed to erase the last n characters in a string:

```
/* Assumes passed string is zero terminated... */
void string_erase_last_char(char * src, int num_chars_to_erase)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);

    if (num_chars_to_erase > len)
    {
        num_chars_to_erase = len;
    }

    src[len - num_chars_to_erase] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest way possible, I believe. I'll be using memory (re)allocation for the time being though, as I need to get used to how it works. Thank you for the suggestion nonetheless, it'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the purpose of the `size` parameter.

If your strings are initially allocated using `malloc()`, you should just use `realloc()` to change their size. That will retain the content automatically, and require fewer operations:

```
int string_erase_end (char ** dst)
{
  size_t len;
  char *ns;

  if (dst == NULL || *dst == NULL)
   return -1;

  len = strlen(*dst);
  if (len == 0)
    return -1;

  ns = realloc(*dst, len - 1);
  if (ns == NULL)
   return -1;
  ns[len - 1] = '\0';
  *dst = ns;

  return 0;
}
```

In the "real world", you would generally not change the allocated size for a 1-char truncation; it's too inefficient. You would instead keep track of the string's length and its allocated size separately. That makes it easy for strings to grow; as long as there is allocated space already, it's very fast to append a character.

Also, in C you never need to cast the return value of `malloc()`; it serves no purpose and can hide bugs so don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for the useful tips, unwind. I tried realloc earlier, but got segmentation faults whenever reducing a string's size (whereas appending to a string works OK with realloc). I'm not sure why.